# Making flexbox responsive

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm using flexbox to create rows of 4 items.

When I resize screen, everything gets smaller, but I also want row to split up into to 2 rows of 2 instead of 1 row of four. And eventually, on really small screens into rows of 1.

I've tried setting different widths, margins and tried to use the @media rule in CSS but I can not get it to function properly.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Code:

```css
.article-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 10px;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.articles {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.articles h2 {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.article {
  width: 22%;
}

.article img {
  width: 100%;
}

.article-title {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.article-creator {
  font-style: italic;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
          <section class="articles">
            <h2>Trending</h2>
            <div class="article-wrapper">
              <div class="article">
                <img src="https://imagejournal.org/wp-content/uploads/bb-plugin/cache/23466317216_b99485ba14_o-panorama.jpg" alt="">
                <p class="article-title">row</p>
                <p class="article-viewcount">row</p>
                <p class="article-creator">row</p>
              </div>
              <div class="article">
                <img src="https://imagejournal.org/wp-content/uploads/bb-plugin/cache/23466317216_b99485ba14_o-panorama.jpg" alt="">
                <p class="article-title">row</p>
                <p class="article-viewcount">row</p>
                <p class="article-creator">row</p>
              </div>
              <div class="article">
                <img src="https://imagejournal.org/wp-content/uploads/bb-plugin/cache/23466317216_b99485ba14_o-panorama.jpg" alt="">
                <p class="article-title">row</p>
                <p class="article-viewcount">row</p>
                <p class="article-creator">row</p>
              </div>
              <div class="article">
                <img src="https://imagejournal.org/wp-content/uploads/bb-plugin/cache/23466317216_b99485ba14_o-panorama.jpg" alt="">
                <p class="article-title">row</p>
                <p class="article-viewcount">row</p>
                <p class="article-creator">row</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </section>
```

Comment: simply update the width using media query, to make it 45% for example

Comment: Use media query. You could assign width to 50% so they will be 2 in row. But you need to specify `flex-wrap` and also when you need into 1 column make them width 100% and parent `flex-direction: column`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `@media` to achieve this

```css
.article-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 10px;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.articles {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.articles h2 {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.article {
  width: 22%;
}

.article img {
  width: 100%;
}

.article-title {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.article-creator {
  font-style: italic;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .article {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="articles">
            <h2>Trending</h2>
            <div class="article-wrapper">
              <div class="article">
                <img src="https://imagejournal.org/wp-content/uploads/bb-plugin/cache/23466317216_b99485ba14_o-panorama.jpg" alt="">
                <p class="article-title">row</p>
                <p class="article-viewcount">row</p>
                <p class="article-creator">row</p>
              </div>
              <div class="article">
                <img src="https://imagejournal.org/wp-content/uploads/bb-plugin/cache/23466317216_b99485ba14_o-panorama.jpg" alt="">
                <p class="article-title">row</p>
                <p class="article-viewcount">row</p>
                <p class="article-creator">row</p>
              </div>
              <div class="article">
                <img src="https://imagejournal.org/wp-content/uploads/bb-plugin/cache/23466317216_b99485ba14_o-panorama.jpg" alt="">
                <p class="article-title">row</p>
                <p class="article-viewcount">row</p>
                <p class="article-creator">row</p>
              </div>
              <div class="article">
                <img src="https://imagejournal.org/wp-content/uploads/bb-plugin/cache/23466317216_b99485ba14_o-panorama.jpg" alt="">
                <p class="article-title">row</p>
                <p class="article-viewcount">row</p>
                <p class="article-creator">row</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </section>
```

working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/07khwcep/1/)

Comment: Welcome :) @rpm192